# WPF XML Cannot bind data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="SQLText"
TextWrapping="Wrap"
AcceptsReturn="True"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
TextAlignment="Left"
Background="#90CCF4"
Grid.Column="2"
Grid.Row="0"
Margin="0,25,0,0"
**behaviors:AutoCompleteBehavior.AutoCompleteItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}"**
>
</TextBox>
```

Here is the back end code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
public ObservableCollection<string> TestItems { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
SQLText.TextChanged += SQLTextTextChanged;


CreateInitialTree();
}



private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
try
{
Settings = DOF.ReadConfig();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
}
}

}
```

For some reason the TestItems isn't binding.
I am following this code i cloned from github: https://github.com/Nimgoble/WPFTextBoxAutoComplete/

I noticed it uses MVVM I'm just attaching it to the main screen while I test.

The error i get in the xalm screen is:

No DataContext Binding found for TestItems, not sure how to fix this error.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `DataContext` to `MainWindow`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    SQLText.TextChanged += SQLTextTextChanged;
    CreateInitialTree();
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, i'm trying to find an easy way to autocomplete/guess what the user is inputting based on a list of strings.